# mysql - calling stored procedure inside another stored procedure

Tags: mysql

Since mysql functions cannot return tables/result sets therefore i created a stored procedure (**Get_StudentsWithAllIndicators**) that does the stuff i needed. Now, i need to use this stored procedure result inside the actual stored procedure(Find_MapDetails) like this.

```
select * from students where studentid in (Get_StudentsWithAllIndicators('7,8', 2));
```

but it does not work! If you are recommending creating a temporary table and insert values into it please tell me the syntax..thanks

**Get_StudentsWithAllIndicators**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Get_StudentsWithAllIndicators`(IN p_list VARCHAR(255), IN p_length int)
 BEGIN
/*make query with the length of indicators in the list*/
DECLARE x  INT;
SET x=1;
SET @queryMain = 'SELECT distinct studentid FROM studentindicators WHERE studentid IN ';
SET @queryWhere = '(SELECT studentid FROM studentindicators WHERE indicatorid = substring_index(\'';
SET @query = '';

WHILE x  <= p_length DO

SET @query =  CONCAT(@query, @queryWhere, p_list, '\', ",", 1)) AND studentId IN ');    
SET x=x+1;
SET @lengthWithCommas = Length(p_list);

SET p_list = substr(p_list, instr(p_list, ',') + 1, @lengthWithCommas - instr(p_list, ','));

END WHILE;

/*remove last AND - note: no occurence of A after AND is expected*/
SET @query = CONCAT(@queryMain, LEFT(@query, LENGTH(@query) - LOCATE('A', REVERSE(@query))));


PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;

 END
```

Comment: I think you should also post the script of the SP

Comment: which one? get_students or find_map?

Comment: Get_StudentsWitHAllIndicators -- Is this SP used somewhere else? I have this feeling that you don't really have to create a SP just for this, anyway, I have submitted an answer below. Could you please check?

Comment: i think this sp will only confuse everyone but i have added it any way :)

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO #MYTEMPTABLE exec Get_StudentsWithAllIndicators('7,8', 2)   

SELECT * FROM students where studentId in (SELECT studentid FROM #MYTEMPTABLE)
```

Save the results of the first sp into a `temp` table.

Comment: do i have to create the temp table before calling insert? it does not work CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp1(
    StudentID int);

INSERT INTO temp1 exec Get_StudentsWithAllIndicators('7,8', 2) ;

Comment: yes you have to create the temp table first. it should have the same column (and column type) with the result set of your first SP

Comment: CREATE TABLE temp1(
    StudentID int);

INSERT INTO temp1 exec Get_StudentsWithAllIndicators('7,8', 2) ;

Comment: Could you try 'CALL' instead of 'EXEC' or remove the 'EXEC' altogether; not very familiar with calling SPs with mySQL

Comment: What syntax error you are getting? Did you try to search on how to insert data from sp to temp table?

Comment: after some trial and error select is working INSERT INTO temp1 select Get_StudentsWithAllIndicators(indicatorIds, noOfIndicators) ;

Comment: but it keeps saying Get_StudentsWithAllIndicators doesnot exist..is it considering my sp as a function?

Comment: I think it's considering your SP as a table; using that format. Have you tried `CALL` instead of `EXEC` ?

Comment: btw can i insert temptable values inside my Get_StudentsWithAllIndicators? PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;